# Ignore Undefined objects in array of arrays variable

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In Google Apps Script, I'm pulling data from an API. In the code below, the "output" variable contains an array of arrays. There is always at least one ["Response"] object, but sometimes there are 2.

My problem is, the code below isn't returning the second object (["Response"][1]) when it is present. I tried removing the "if" statement, but I get an error saying "TypeError: Cannot read property "Product" from undefined".

Does anyone know how to get the second object when it's present and ignore it when it's not?

```
      var data = reportAPI();
      var applications = data["applications"];
      var output = []

      applications.forEach(function(elem,i) {
        output.push(["ID",elem["Id"]]);
        output.push([elem["Response"][0]["Product"],elem["Response"][0]["Status"]]);
          if (["Response"][1] != null) {
            output.push([elem["Response"][1]["Product"],elem["Response"][1]["Status"]]);
          }
       }
```

P.S. I would even be happy with replacing the undefined object with "", but I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: Just reread `if (["Response"][1] != null)` carefully and you'll see something important is missing here: `elem`. By the way, in JavaScript it is customary to use dot notation for properties: `data.applications` instead of `data["applications"]`, and so on: `elem.Response[1].Product`, etc

Comment: @CrazyIvan thank you so much for the spot - this has worked! I feel silly for not trying it. And thanks for the advice on the JavaScript customs, I'm still very new to it so this is useful to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this modification? Please think of this as one of several answers. I used `forEach` to `elem["Response"]`. By this, values can be pushed by the number of `elem["Response"]`.

#### From :

```
applications.forEach(function(elem,i) {
  output.push(["ID",elem["Id"]]);
  output.push([elem["Response"][0]["Product"],elem["Response"][0]["Status"]]);
  if (["Response"][1] != null) {
    output.push([elem["Response"][1]["Product"],elem["Response"][1]["Status"]]);
  }
}
```

#### To :

```
applications.forEach(function(elem) {
  output.push(["ID",elem["Id"]]);
  elem["Response"].forEach(function(elem2) {
    output.push([elem2["Product"],elem2["Status"]]);
  });
});
```

If this didn't work, please tell me. I would like to modify.

Comment: This is fantastic, works perfectly, thank you very much. It cut down on the size of my code considerably and made it much more easily scalable.

Comment: @Robert Samarji Welcome. I'm glad your problem was solved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 0):

The example below helps to account for the cases where the Response[0] or Reponse[1] are not "undefined" or "null". Putting !() will turn the Boolean values for "undefined" or "null" to true.

```
applications.forEach(function(elem,i) {
  output.push(["ID",elem.Id]);
  if(!(elem.Reponse[0]))
    output.push([elem.Response[0].Product,elem.Response[0].Status]);
  if (!(elem.Response[1])) {
    output.push([elem.Response[1].Product,elem.Response[1]Status]);
  }
}
```